# textarea live character counting + Preview not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get live character count + live preview of an textarea usign pure JS no Jquery, but getting some error. Here my code

```js
var wpcomment = document.getElementById('text');

wpcomment.onkeyup = wpcomment.onkeypress = function(){
    document.getElementById('DrevCom').innerHTML = this.value;
}
function count()
{
  var total=document.getElementById("text").value;
  total=total.replace(/\s/g, '');
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML="Total Characters:"+total.length;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text" onkeyup="count();"  placeholder="Add comments:"></textarea>



<p id="total">Total Characters:0</p>
<div id="DrevCom"></div>
```

Comment: Dont see any error - what error are you seeing? You're never calling `count` by the looks of it.

Comment: it shows preview well but doesn't show character count

Comment: Yeah, you're never calling `count` as I mentioned.

Comment: can you fix it for me, I tried too many times!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `onkeyup` property in HTML to `count()`, and then you are overwriting it with Javascript. You can only have one `onKeyup` property, so either use an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead, or have the one function call the other.

```js
var wpcomment = document.getElementById('text');

wpcomment.onkeyup = wpcomment.onkeypress = function(){
    document.getElementById('DrevCom').innerHTML = this.value;
    count()
}
function count()
{
  var total=document.getElementById("text").value;
  total=total.replace(/\s/g, '');
  console.log(total);
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML="Total Characters:"+total.length;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text"  placeholder="Add comments:"></textarea>



<p id="total">Total Characters:0</p>
<div id="DrevCom"></div>
```

Comment: Having only one event listener should be the way to go, and you can then split the code inside that listener in multiple functions if you want.

Comment: Aah! I missed it! Thanks